# Paypal Checkout session expired - Codeigniter CI Merchant with Paypal

Tags: paypal, ci-merchant

I've been trying to set up CI Merchant with Codeigniter and Paypal. In sandbox mode after attempting a transaction the following error occurs:

```
This Express Checkout session has expired. Token value is no longer valid.
```

I can't seem to find out why this might happen. Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: How long are you waiting between the time that you receive the token til the time that you try to use the token in an API again?  Can you provide the full response that you are getting back, I can use the correlation id to look it up on my end and see what may be causing the issue.